# Error running Jhipster-generated war on Linux machine

Tags: jhipster

I use Jhipster v6.10.1.

I generated a war following JHipster recommandations (https://www.jhipster.tech/production/). I changed pom xml to

```
  -    <packaging>jar</packaging>
  +    <packaging>war</packaging>

      <id>prod</id>
      <dependencies>
          <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
  +           <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

Then, I apply this command :

```
mvn -Pprod clean package
```

The result is that I can run the war file using this command on **WINDOWS** (my dev environment) :

```
java -jar myapp.war
```

However, I can't run the war file using this command on **LINUX** (the prod environment) :

```
sudo chmod 777 myapp.war 

sudo nohup ./myapp.war --spring.profiles.active=prod -Xms512m -Xmx1024M
```

Indeed, on LINUX server, I get this error :

[image]

This error is not very informative and I don't find any clue about how to run Jhipster 6.10.1 app on Linux. Importantly, I run two other JHipster apps (v5.0.1 and v5.2.1) on the same linux server, and they work properly.

To note, I also tried to do the same with a production JAR following JHipster recommandation. It leads to same result : run on Windows, not on Linux.

Can you help me please?

Thks

EDIT 1 : see head when-and-where-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar cmd result

[image]

Comment: Why do you want a war package if you don't deploy into a server? You're using it as if it was an executable jar but you don't get all its benefits like systemd integration which does not require `nohup`. https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-systemd-service

Comment: I did a war package because this is the way the other packages were made before in my company. I can use the jar this is not a problem. But as I precize in the question, I tried also with a jar file and it gave me the same error.

Comment: I did it. Please see EDIT 1.

Comment: How can I check for this configuration? (To note, I didn't change anything on configuration). I do nothing different for file transfer for this app than for the other apps that I succeed to get running. How do I check the checksum?

Comment: Check your *effective* pom with `.\mvnw help:effective-pom` and read the spring boot docs. On Linux use `cksum` command, on Windows ask Google ;)

Comment: I did effective-pom, for spring-boot-maven-plugin, this is 2.2.7.RELEASE. I didn't change anything to basic configuration and I don't know what to look in spring boot docs. For cksum I did it on Linux, but didn't find a good way on windows. Moreover, I transfer all my other apps the same way, and if I tranfer my jar to an other windows server, it works... My problem seems to be linked to Linux environment...?

Comment: Importantly, I just created a testapp without any change using JHipster with same version. On Windows, I can run it, on Linux I can't, the error is the same. Did you tried to deploy the app v6.10.1 on a linux server before?

Comment: Forget what I said about `head` of the jar because I did not follow the docs to run it as a service https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#run. I generated an app with 6.10.4 and correctly executed it on Linux Centos 8 with `java -jar test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`.

Comment: So, I think the problem is specific to your environment and not to JHipster. You could confirm it by generating a simpler app with https://start.spring.io/ and I still think that you should ensure that jar is not corrupted by comparing checksums on both systems, don't you have WSL running on your Windows PC?

Comment: Ok. When I don't use nohup the application starts. My issue now is how to perform the same as nohup that is to say being active after user logout. I tried the service part with init.d described in JHipster wich doesn't work in my hands - service not found (this might be another question). You talked about system d with a ref which seems to be generic. Do you have one specific to JHipster apps?

Comment: Don't use init.d for services,  it's deprecated in favor of systemd and it's much easier to configure. Nothing specific to JHipster here, it's pure Spring Boot and systemd stuff: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-systemd-service For a padawan, it's highly recommended to invest some time to understand what you can do in a service unit. What do you use to automate your deployment? Tools like Ansible help a lot with services

Comment: Ok I will dive in systemd :) Thanks for your help! We don't use anything to automate deployment for now. We were thinking about Jenkins but we didn't go further yet.

Comment: Jenkins is not really the right tool although it can be used to trigger a deployment tool like Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to discussion seen in comments above:

"nohup" was not compatible with the war/jar packages produced with JHipster v6.10.1.

Solution used to deploy my app (even after user logout) was to use systemd :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment.html#deployment-systemd-service